# Are there any better ways to implement CSS :nth-child for elements that have recursive/repeatable properties?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I would like to do some simple animations of 4 `<div>`. However, its really recursive as the propery `animation: animate 1s forwards` are the same for all, and the only property changing is the `animation-delay` which just follows a basic increment. Are there any better ways to do this? Thanks in advance!

```
    div:nth-child(1) {
      position: absolute;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: maroon;
      top: 0;
      animation: animate 1s forwards;
      animation-delay: 0.2s;
    }
    
    div:nth-child(2) {
      position: absolute;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      top: 70px;
      background-color: maroon;
      animation: animate 1s forwards;
      animation-delay: 0.2s;
    }
    
    
    div:nth-child(3) {
      position: absolute;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: maroon;
      top: 140px;
      animation: animate 1s forwards;
      animation-delay: 0.3s;
    }
    
    div:nth-child(4) {
      position: absolute;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: maroon;
      top: 210px;
      animation: animate 1s forwards;
      animation-delay: 0.4s;
    }
    
    
    
    @keyframes animate{
      from{
        left: 0;
      }
      to{
        left: 10vw;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why SCSS is used. Here is an example: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for. Final result in compiled CSS file would be the same, but you can generate styles in SCSS without hard coding them, through loops and with variables.

You can group the code though, by creating a class that every child would have:

```
.common-styles-class-name {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: maroon;
    animation: animate 1s forwards;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0;
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
    top: 70px;
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
    top: 140px;
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

div:nth-child(4) {
    top: 210px;
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
```